# Postback is not working in Safari in Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, safari, postback, viewstate

Our QA team reported that one of our applications is not working in Safari in Windows 7. After checking the problem we figured out that any postback event is not working. After some tries we found that Page.IsPostback() reports false and thinks it’s a first-time load of the page and postback did not include ViewState.

We tried many solutions including
[ASP.Net postback problem with ViewState in Safari on Windows 7](http://www.ablemods.com/Blog/post/2012/07/20/ASPNet-postback-problem-with-ViewState-in-Safari-on-Windows-7.aspx)
[Viewstate invalid when using Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189/viewstate-invalid-when-using-safari)
[ViewState Chunking in ASP.NET 2.0 (maxPageStateFieldLength)](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2007/04/17/viewstate-chunking-in-asp-net-2-0-maxpagestatefieldlength.aspx)

but all didn't bring Safari to work.

There is nothing special about this application. It is normal pages that use one master page that is a very normal master page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestions. 1. Check for javascript errors, 2. Compress and cut in smaller pieces the view state.

Comment: @Aristos, there are no javascript errors. Also, I cut the viewstate into multiple fields but the same issue is still there, any postback considered as a totally new postback :(

Comment: What do you see ? is the post back happens or not happens at all and be there waiting for ever ?

Comment: @Aristos, postback happens but Page.IsPostback() reports false and thinks it’s a first-time load of the page and postback did not include ViewState.

Comment: So you try to make post back and you have reload. Can you see if a javascript code make this issue ?

Comment: @kman0, nope still have the same issue? What about you?

Comment: @kman0: I figured out how to resolve that issue. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari has an issue when working with Windows Authentication under IIS if Negotiate provider is enabled so AJAX POST is not working.

**How to resolve?**
In IIS, go to the Authentication settings of your website. Right click on Windows Authentication, choose providers and remove Negotiate, leaving NTLM this makes everything works fine.

**[References]**
[AJAX POST Request Only Works Once in Safari 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613196/ajax-post-request-only-works-once-in-safari-5)
[Negotiate Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) article in Wikipedia shows that it is not implemented in Safari

Comment: You doesn't have to go in the ISS (International Space Station), but in IIS is enough ;) Joking aside, for IIS Express, you will find this configuration in the file `C:\Users\[Username]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` and search for the `windowsAuthentication` section within the `<security>` section.